# Application.LoadLevel Works once but not the second time?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a small game and have just set up a home menu for it. When the home screen loads, you can click the level button and it will successfully load the game.
However, if I then return to the home screen and attempt to reload the level, it loads but nothing works. No player movement, no AI movement, nothing.

The code I have to load the level is this:

```
public GameObject loadingImage;

public void LoadScene(int level)
{
    loadingImage.SetActive(true);
    Application.LoadLevel(level);
}
```

and I use exactly the same scenario to return home.

I am not too sure why this isn't working how I intend. Do I have to unload a level first or something along those lines? I have no idea. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much!

***NOTE: This issue has now been fixed.***

The error was due to my pause menu using `Time.timeScale = 0` and not reverting it back. To code was:

```
void Awake()
{
    isPause = false;
}
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
    {
        isPause = !isPause;
         if(isPause == true)
        {
            Time.timeScale = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            Time.timeScale = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Due to this, when I now load the scene, it ensures `isPause` is always equal to false.

Comment: You may need to add some more code. There might be some other function causing the problem you got.

Comment: I agree with @0014's comment. If your scene is loading, then the `Application.LoadLevel()` method itself is working, because that is it's sole purpose. Something else may be causing the objects not to work.

Comment: Also, consider using http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html if you're on the latest Unity version.

Comment: @andeart, thanks for the responses! The only reason I'm so unsure about this is that it loads 100% fine and is playable the first time. Its just pausing the game, returning home and then reloading the scene causes the problem. Could be that the game is still paused possibly, I'll try that. Thanks for the responses again!

Comment: Just a suspicion: are you messing with `Time.timeScale` somewhere? Ensure you're setting the right states with it if you are.

Comment: @andeart, yeah that is it exactly. I set Time.timeScale to 0 and never return it to 1. Thank you very much for your help! Greatly appreciated!

Comment: Great! I suggest you post that in an answer here yourself and select it as an answer, so that others can know there's no more solving required here.

Comment: Thanks again for your time @andeart, appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered now. Thanks to comments from @andeart.

The issue I was having was I used `Time.timeScale = 0;` when pausing the game and I never returned the value back to 1. So, because the game was paused, when it was reloaded, it remained paused.

If you come across this issue, be sure to check that you haven't made a similar error to me. I wont be making it again.

Technically, `Application.LoadLevel` worked as expected, however I made the error of not "Unpausing" the game.

Thanks everyone for the responses!

Comment: It may be worth editing your question to include the code where you're setting the `timeScale`. That way, future readers will be able to understand the problem you faced without needing to read the comments.

Comment: Yeah sure, I'll do that now!